# Horizontal placement of footnotes in beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes

Hi I am wondering whether it is possible to place the beamer footnotes into multiple columns or display as horizontal, instead of vertical.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
%  \caption{Add caption}
            \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
    \centering
    Animal estimated by tracking  & \textbf{2 Equation approach} & 1 Equation \\
    50\%   & $\frac{\partial C\footnote{dye }(t,\vec{x})}{}$      &  \\
     &  $\frac{\partial \alpha\footnote{age }(t,\vec{x})}{}$     & $\frac{\partial A\footnote{A refers to "animal"}}{}$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}%
%  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could explain me how to get the horizontal footnotes.

Comment: Both things are solved somewhere in the TeXbook (maybe it's even in Appendix D, I'm not sure).  The question is whether those solutions will work with Beamer.  (Or whether there are LaTeX packages doing the same - probably yes - and whether *they* will work with Beamer.)

Comment: @mbork you're right; it's Appendix D ;-) Perhaps those solutions will work in `beamer` (I don't know for sure). In any case, standard LaTeX packages for this requirement like `footmisc`, `bigfoot` or `manyfoot` won't work with `beamer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard LaTeX packages like `footmisc`, `bigfoot` or `manyfoot` won't be usable here with `beamer` (they're either incompatible or produce undesired effects).

Here's one possibility to have multicolumn (well, two-column in this case) footnotes; some re-definitions of internal commands were required (the new code is marked `%NEW`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
% All the following is NEW
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]%
{\parindent 0em\everypar={\hangafter 1\hangindent  0em}\raggedright
\noindent\@makefnmark\hskip 1em\ignorespaces#1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand<>\beamer@framefootnotetext[1]{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@footins\vbox{%
    \hsize0.5\framewidth%NEW
    \textwidth\hsize
    \columnwidth\hsize
    \unvbox\beamer@footins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \uncover#2{\@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}}%
    \color@endgroup}}
\def\beamer@autobreakframebox{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
  \ifbeamer@autobreak%
    % Ok, frame was overful -> split it!
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight%
    \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\beamer@framebox%
    \@tempdima=\ht\beamer@splitbox%
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\beamer@autobreaklastheight%
      \global\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\@tempdima\relax%
    \else%
      \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\unvbox\beamer@splitbox}%
      \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
    \fi%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\@tempboxa%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak%
      \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%
        \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
        \else%
          \begingroup
            \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
            \footnoterule %
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%NEW
\begin{multicols}{2}%NEW
            \unvbox \beamer@footins%
\end{multicols}%NEW
            \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
          \endgroup  
        \fi%
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode%
    }%
  \else%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\beamer@framebox%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskip%
      \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
      \else%
        \begingroup
          \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
          \footnoterule %
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%NEW
\begin{multicols}{2}%NEW
          \unvbox \beamer@footins %
\end{multicols}%NEW
          \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
        \endgroup 
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode}%
    \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
  \fi%
  }
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multicolumn footnotes}
Some\footnote{A first footnote with some additional text just for the example; and now I add some more text and perhaps some additional text to see if it works as intended} test text\footnote{A second footnote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a personal opinion, I don't like much standard footnotes, and I like less multicolumn footnotes.

Comment: Notice that multicol has an unusual licence.  (Not that it's *bad*, but definitely *unusual*.)

Answer (score 1):

The [`parnotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes?lang=en) package can do this for you. Just add the package and use `\parnote` instead of `\footnote`, and then issue `\parnotes` where you want them printed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
%  \caption{Add caption}
            \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
    \centering
    Animal estimated by tracking  & \textbf{2 Equation approach} & 1 Equation \\
    50\%   & $\frac{\partial C\parnote{dye }(t,\vec{x})}{}$      &  \\
     &  $\frac{\partial \alpha\parnote{age }(t,\vec{x})}{}$     & $\frac{\partial A\parnote{A refers to "animal"}}{}$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}%
%  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
%\vfill % <-- compare difference
\parnotes
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I suppose this package makes it easy to have paragraphed footnotes in your slides. The question you should ask yourself is whether they are necessary or if there is a smarter and less distracting way to convey that information.