# Footnotes in a single paragraph in Beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes

The answer to [Horizontal placement of footnotes in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120092/horizontal-placement-of-footnotes-in-beamer) shows how to have two columns of footnotes in beamer, but it doesn't answer how to have footnotes in a single paragraph separated by commas.

footmisc does not work with beamer.

How can I redefine or patch commands to allow footnotes in the format desired?

beamerbaseframecomponents.sty seems to be the file to work with, but so far I haven't had success editing things. I've made footnotes disappear, changed fonts and spacing, but I just can't put it all on one line!

Comment: Please do not do this. Do you seriously expect your audience to deal not only with footnotes (already dubious in a presentation) but with a mass of footnotes presented as a solid block? Why would you have so many footnotes ***in a presentation*** anyway? If this information is really crucial, you need to rethink how to communicate it. If not, drop it.

Comment: @cfr - the footnotes contain the citations from a table. It is essential that they are on the page, but seriously hinders reading of the table if they are inline with the data. There are too many of them to fit on a slide in the usual vertical footnote style.

Comment: But what purpose do they serve on the slide? Will people be able to read and absorb the information they provide? If not, what's the point?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. They're an academic requirement. Having the citations on the slide allows people to see where I got information from. I don't really expect anyone to actually pay attention to the citations there and then, but if I don't put them in I am open to accusations of plagiarism.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is one of fields: I'm using an author-date style, so I usually have citations like (Adams, 2010) directly after a point & references at the end of the presentation. It is a bit unwieldy in tables so I'm using a footnote with the citation, but the full bibliographical entry is still on the last slide.

Comment: Then provide that information on a handout. It doesn't belong on your slides. Slides are not like chunks from a paper. They supplement what you are saying. While I sometimes include some references, you have to keep these to a minimum. If you don't expect your audience to read it, it doesn't belong on the slide. (I guess one exception is that I'll sometimes include an image where I need to provide an image credit.) You can then *say* that your sources for the information are included on the handout people have. Or, if you must, you can include a footnote to that effect.

Comment: Whilst I certainly appreciate the importance of direct and uncluttered slides, what you are suggesting just would not be acceptable in my situation. The presence of the references is a strict requirement, not something I have decided myself, and inline, comma-separated footnotes would improve the readability of the rest of the slide. In my current presentation, I've ended up doing this manually. I'm hoping I will find a technical solution for the future.

Comment: That is a barmy requirement. Are slides also a requirement? If not, I'd go with a handout instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30103/discussion-between-greenglass-and-cfr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way. Be careful not to abuse the power `parnotes` provides....

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parnotes}% https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes?lang=en

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My Frame}
Some important thoughts:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo\parnote{First note}
        \item Bar\parnote{Second note}
        \item Baz\parnote{Third note}
    \end{itemize}
%\vfill % <-- compare difference
\parnotes
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```