# Put footnotes in two columns

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer and use footnotes as follows:

```
 \footnote[frame]{\cite{ref}};
```

but if the they are more than three, they get truncated.

How to split them over two columns so I can see them all?

UPDATE:

[image: error]

Comment: for styling I want to split them into two columns also not only because they don't fit

Comment: the snapshot of the error is in the UPDATE

Comment: This https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120119/36296 might or might not work -- impossible to say if you don't provide a test document.

Comment: You really need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in order for others to be able to help you.